# split character column into multiple columns

Tags: r

What I am trying to do is split a character column into multiple columns without losing the additional data in the df and the number of columns is variable depending on the input. I guess it's easier with an example:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1:4), b = c("bla", "word", "otherword", "nice"), c = c("one \n two \n three", "bla \n why \n morebla \n helpme", "bla \n bla", "bla"))
```

I want to split column c into multiple columns by sep = "\n".

I tried using `seperate(df$c, "\n", 10)` but it doesn't work because I use character as separator. 10 is just an idea, so that I rather have more columns than needed instead of dropping info.
I tried using `str_split_fixed(df$c, "\n", 10)` which works fine, but it deletes column a and b and I don't know why or how I could fix this.

Additional info: in the end I want to use the command on a list.

Edit:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = c(1:4), b = c("bla", "word", "otherword", "nice"), c = c("one \n two \n three", "bla \n why \n morebla \n helpme", "bla \n bla", "bla"))
df2 <- data.frame(a = c(1:4), b = c("bla", "word", "otherword", "nice"), c = c("one \n two \n three", "bla \n why \n morebla \n helpme", "bla \n bla  \n ghfdghf \n hdhdh \n hjgfj \n td", "bla"))

map(list(df1, df2), ~.x %>% separate(c, into = paste0('c', seq_len(max(str_count(.x$c, '\n')+1))), sep = '\n', fill = 'right'))

[[1]]
  a         b   c1    c2        c3      c4
1 1       bla one   two      three    <NA>
2 2      word bla   why   morebla   helpme
3 3 otherword bla    bla      <NA>    <NA>
4 4      nice  bla  <NA>      <NA>    <NA>

[[2]]
  a         b   c1     c2        c3      c4      c5   c6
1 1       bla one    two      three    <NA>    <NA> <NA>
2 2      word bla    why   morebla   helpme    <NA> <NA>
3 3 otherword bla   bla    ghfdghf   hdhdh   hjgfj    td
4 4      nice  bla   <NA>      <NA>    <NA>    <NA> <NA> 

df <- data.frame(unlist(list))
```

I guess this could cause problems as number of columns are not the same within the list.
Expected outcome:

```
  a         b   c1     c2        c3      c4      c5   c6
1 1       bla one   two      three    <NA>     <NA>  <NA>
2 2      word bla   why   morebla   helpme     <NA>  <NA>
3 3 otherword bla    bla      <NA>    <NA>     <NA>  <NA>
4 4      nice  bla  <NA>      <NA>    <NA>     <NA>  <NA>
5 1       bla one    two      three    <NA>    <NA> <NA>
6 2      word bla    why   morebla   helpme    <NA> <NA>
7 3 otherword bla   bla    ghfdghf   hdhdh   hjgfj    td
8 4      nice  bla   <NA>      <NA>    <NA>    <NA> <NA>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If doing in tidyverse/dplyr pipe kinda syntax, you may use `separate` from `tidyr` in conjunction with `stringr::str_count` which does exactly as you require.

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1:4), b = c("bla", "word", "otherword", "nice"), c = c("one \n two \n three", "bla \n why \n morebla \n helpme", "bla \n bla", "bla"))

library(tidyverse)
df %>% separate(c, into = paste0('c', seq_len(max(str_count(df$c, '\n')+1))), sep = '\n', fill = 'right')

  a         b   c1    c2        c3      c4
1 1       bla one   two      three    <NA>
2 2      word bla   why   morebla   helpme
3 3 otherword bla    bla      <NA>    <NA>
4 4      nice  bla  <NA>      <NA>    <NA>
```

---

For doing it on list of data.frames, do it like this

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = c(1:4), b = c("bla", "word", "otherword", "nice"), c = c("one \n two \n three", "bla \n why \n morebla \n helpme", "bla \n bla", "bla"))
df2 <- data.frame(a = c(1:4), b = c("bla", "word", "otherword", "nice"), c = c("one \n two \n three", "bla \n why \n morebla \n helpme", "bla \n bla  \n ghfdghf \n hdhdh \n hjgfj \n td", "bla"))

map(list(df1, df2), ~.x %>% separate(c, into = paste0('c', seq_len(max(str_count(.x$c, '\n')+1))), sep = '\n', fill = 'right'))

[[1]]
  a         b   c1    c2        c3      c4
1 1       bla one   two      three    <NA>
2 2      word bla   why   morebla   helpme
3 3 otherword bla    bla      <NA>    <NA>
4 4      nice  bla  <NA>      <NA>    <NA>

[[2]]
  a         b   c1     c2        c3      c4      c5   c6
1 1       bla one    two      three    <NA>    <NA> <NA>
2 2      word bla    why   morebla   helpme    <NA> <NA>
3 3 otherword bla   bla    ghfdghf   hdhdh   hjgfj    td
4 4      nice  bla   <NA>      <NA>    <NA>    <NA> <NA>
```

---

**Further Edit in view of revised question**

1. Use `map_dfr` instead

```
map_dfr(list(df1, df2), ~.x %>% separate(c, into = paste0('c', seq_len(max(str_count(.x$c, '\n')+1))), sep = '\n', fill = 'right'))

  a         b   c1     c2        c3      c4      c5   c6
1 1       bla one    two      three    <NA>    <NA> <NA>
2 2      word bla    why   morebla   helpme    <NA> <NA>
3 3 otherword bla     bla      <NA>    <NA>    <NA> <NA>
4 4      nice  bla   <NA>      <NA>    <NA>    <NA> <NA>
5 1       bla one    two      three    <NA>    <NA> <NA>
6 2      word bla    why   morebla   helpme    <NA> <NA>
7 3 otherword bla   bla    ghfdghf   hdhdh   hjgfj    td
8 4      nice  bla   <NA>      <NA>    <NA>    <NA> <NA>
```

2. But I cannot see a reason why doing it on separate items of list and then r-binding instead of first r-binding and then simply doing it without `map*`

```
df1 %>% rbind(df2) %>% separate(c, into = paste0('c', seq_len(max(str_count(.$c, '\n')+1))), sep = '\n', fill = 'right')

  a         b   c1     c2        c3      c4      c5   c6
1 1       bla one    two      three    <NA>    <NA> <NA>
2 2      word bla    why   morebla   helpme    <NA> <NA>
3 3 otherword bla     bla      <NA>    <NA>    <NA> <NA>
4 4      nice  bla   <NA>      <NA>    <NA>    <NA> <NA>
5 1       bla one    two      three    <NA>    <NA> <NA>
6 2      word bla    why   morebla   helpme    <NA> <NA>
7 3 otherword bla   bla    ghfdghf   hdhdh   hjgfj    td
8 4      nice  bla   <NA>      <NA>    <NA>    <NA> <NA>
```

Comment: Thank you. it works fine when I apply it to one df, however when I apply it to the list of dfs, I obviously get variable numbers of columns which makes it hard to combine the list to one df later. Do you have an idea how to fix this problem? So maybe just say into = paste0 ('c', 1:10). Then I will have a fix number of 10 columns right?

Comment: Sorry, I think you missunderstood, what I was trying to say. In the end, I want to bind all elements of the list to one data frame which I think will be problematic if every element of the lists has a different number of columns. So in your examp I would want that [[1]] also has the column c5 and c6 but filled with NAs. I could also do that when I combine them in the end but I dont know how to do this... I planned to use `data.frame(unlist(list))`

Answer (score 1):

```r
cc = strsplit(df$c, "\n")
l = max(lengths(cc))
CC = lapply(cc, function(x) c(x, rep(NA, l-length(x))))
CC = do.call(rbind, CC)
cbind(df[c('a', 'b')], CC)

a         b    1     2         3       4
1       bla one   two      three    <NA>
2      word bla   why   morebla   helpme
3 otherword bla    bla      <NA>    <NA>
4      nice  bla  <NA>      <NA>    <NA>
```